# Why cakephp project is is not running is server?

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cpanel

I have developed an application using cakephp.Project is running successfully on my local server and test live server.But Its not running in my real domain named http://www.tileclock.com.I tried everything,all is good.I have no idea whats the problem.Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app/config/core.php file just remove comment from the line

```
`Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));`
```

I think you will find solution by above instruction.